# Wordpres Elementor Theme Builder page not loading properly

Tags: wordpress, elementor

So I have this wordpress website hosted with wordpress, I have both Elementor & Elementor Pro plugins enabled, but when I go to the theme builder page I see this.

[theme builder page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J8Zw.png)

Has anyone experienced this? should I reinstall the plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, I ask a question then find the answer, here's what I did to fix it for future people:

Deactivate the "Page Optimize" plugin.

Have a nice day all.